# Completing dates with character column of first and lasts in R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset which contains sensor data overtime. There is a column that details the sensor ID column of dates which contain the day a sensor records an animal, a column that contains what animal was captured in that day and a total number of animals captured. I want to find out the number of days which sensors were active over a period of time. The sensor did not record information everyday and therefore I want to add rows of data for days that are missing. In the species column there is a value of "first" which depicts the first day a sensor was deployed and a "last" for the last day the sensor was functioning. I want to fill in missing days only between the date of the first and last functioning days.

```
ID  Date        Species  Total
A1  2021-01-01  First    
A1  2021-01-02  Mouse    1
A1  2021-01-03  Mouse    2
A1  2021-01-05  Mouse    1
A1  2021-01-06  Last    
B1  2021-01-05  First
B1  2021-01-07  Mouse    2
B1  2021-01-08  Mouse    1
B1  2021-01-10  Mouse    2
B1  2021-01-12  Last
```

I have numerous sensors and numerous sensor deployments over time. What I want to have is.

```
ID  Date        Species  Total
A1  2021-01-01  First    
A1  2021-01-02  Mouse    1
A1  2021-01-03  Mouse    2
A1  2021-01-04  Empty    NA
A1  2021-01-05  Mouse    1
A1  2021-01-06  Last    
B1  2021-01-05  First
B1  2021-01-06  Empty    NA
B1  2021-01-07  Mouse    2
B1  2021-01-08  Mouse    1
B1  2021-01-09  Empty    NA
B1  2021-01-10  Mouse    2
B1  2021-01-11  Empty    NA
B1  2021-01-12  Last
```

I am not to sure where to start with this, I was thinking of using something like dplyr's complete function to fill in the empty days but I am unsure of how I can make it only fill in days between the first and last dates.

Any help is much appreciated as I am still rather new to the R world!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a way to do this in order to preserve performance, but usually when dealing with **complex work BY group** I use `data.table`.

```
library(tribble)
df <- tribble(
  ~ID,  ~Date, ~Species, ~Total,
  'A1',  '2021-01-01',  'First','',
  'A1',  '2021-01-02',  'Mouse','1',
  'A1',  '2021-01-03',  'Mouse','2',
  'A1',  '2021-01-05',  'Mouse','1',
  'A1',  '2021-01-06',  'Last','',
  'B1',  '2021-01-05',  'First','',
  'B1',  '2021-01-07',  'Mouse','2',
  'B1',  '2021-01-08',  'Mouse','1',
  'B1',  '2021-01-10',  'Mouse',    '2',
  'B1',  '2021-01-12',  'Last',     ''
) %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))
```

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)

dt[, {
  first = as.Date(.SD[Species == 'First', Date]) # Get first date
  last = as.Date(.SD[Species == 'Last', Date]) # Get second date
  all_days = seq(first, last, 1) # get all days in between

  # construct template result
  imputed = data.table(ID = .SD$ID[1], Date = all_days, Species = 'Empty', Total = NA_character_) 

  # Left Join .SD onto imptuted to update known values
  # .SD is readonly so cant do antoher way around
  imputed[.SD, on = 'Date', `:=`(Species = i.Species, Total = i.Total)] 
  
  imputed # Return result
  
}, by = ID] # Group by ID

## Result
   ID       Date Species Total
 1: A1 2021-01-01   First      
 2: A1 2021-01-02   Mouse     1
 3: A1 2021-01-03   Mouse     2
 4: A1 2021-01-04   Empty  <NA>
 5: A1 2021-01-05   Mouse     1
 6: A1 2021-01-06    Last      
 7: B1 2021-01-05   First      
 8: B1 2021-01-06   Empty  <NA>
 9: B1 2021-01-07   Mouse     2
10: B1 2021-01-08   Mouse     1
11: B1 2021-01-09   Empty  <NA>
12: B1 2021-01-10   Mouse     2
13: B1 2021-01-11   Empty  <NA>
14: B1 2021-01-12    Last
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
df %>%
  group_by(ID )%>%
  summarise(Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), by = '1 day'), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  left_join(df) %>%
  replace_na(list(Species = 'Empty'))
# A tibble: 14 x 4
   ID    Date       Species Total
   <chr> <date>     <chr>   <int>
 1 A1    2021-01-01 First      NA
 2 A1    2021-01-02 Mouse       1
 3 A1    2021-01-03 Mouse       2
 4 A1    2021-01-04 Empty      NA
 5 A1    2021-01-05 Mouse       1
 6 A1    2021-01-06 Last       NA
 7 B1    2021-01-05 First      NA
 8 B1    2021-01-06 Empty      NA
 9 B1    2021-01-07 Mouse       2
10 B1    2021-01-08 Mouse       1
11 B1    2021-01-09 Empty      NA
12 B1    2021-01-10 Mouse       2
13 B1    2021-01-11 Empty      NA
14 B1    2021-01-12 Last       NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr::complete` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  complete(Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), by = 'day'), 
           fill = list(Species = 'Empty')) %>%
  ungroup

#   ID    Date       Species Total
#   <chr> <date>     <chr>   <chr>
# 1 A1    2021-01-01 First   ""   
# 2 A1    2021-01-02 Mouse   "1"  
# 3 A1    2021-01-03 Mouse   "2"  
# 4 A1    2021-01-04 Empty    NA  
# 5 A1    2021-01-05 Mouse   "1"  
# 6 A1    2021-01-06 Last    ""   
# 7 B1    2021-01-05 First   ""   
# 8 B1    2021-01-06 Empty    NA  
# 9 B1    2021-01-07 Mouse   "2"  
#10 B1    2021-01-08 Mouse   "1"  
#11 B1    2021-01-09 Empty    NA  
#12 B1    2021-01-10 Mouse   "2"  
#13 B1    2021-01-11 Empty    NA  
#14 B1    2021-01-12 Last    ""
```